# Open space delimited textfile in Excel with multible spaces

Tags: excel, text, import

I am trying to import a space delimited textfile into Excel but the trouble is that it an unknown  number of spaces instaed of only one. I now wonder if someone could help me removing all empty cells in a fast way, before or after the import? It is about 1000000 rows and maby a hundred columns including all the empty ones. This is my code so far.

```
currentFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("PRN Files (*.prn), *.prn")
If fileToOpen <> False Then
 Sheets("Rawdata").Cells.ClearContents ' clear raw_data worksheet
 Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fileToOpen, DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True
 openedFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 Workbooks(openedFile).ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Workbooks(currentFile).Worksheets("Rawdata").Range("A1")
Workbooks(openedFile).Close
Else
 MsgBox "No data imported"
End If
```

Sincerely,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach:

- get the data
- remove all extra spaces
- put all the data in column **A**
- parse the data into multiple columns

here is the code:

```
Sub OpenPrnFile()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, filetoOpen As String
    Dim i As Long, s As String, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    filetoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("PRN Files (*.prn), *.prn")
    If filetoOpen = "" Then Exit Sub

    Close #1
    Open filetoOpen For Input As #1
    sh.Select
    i = 1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, s
        Cells(i, 1) = wf.Trim(s)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Close #1

    For j = 1 To i
        ary = Split(Cells(j, 1), " ")
        For k = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            Cells(j, k + 1).Value = ary(k)
        Next k
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly. The only problem is that it is a rather slow process. A normal file takes 25 seconds to load on a very fast PC. Is there a way to improve the speed. I tried Application.ScreenUpdating = False but it not help much.